# Array is affecting digitalread values

Tags: arduino-uno

i want to turn on an led with two buttons. If either of the buttons is pressed i want the led to turn on while the button is pressed and stay off if nothing is pressed. i have two sets of code, they both do the same thing, but the second set of code causes the led to stay in the on position even when nothing is being pushed and i dont understand why.. i am using pulldown resistors on both the buttons.

This is the first set of code that works properly:

```
class Button {

  public:

    int pin;
    int state;
    int location;
    int Speed;
    int Direction;
    int active;
    int prevstate;

    Button(int pin1, int state1, int location1, int active1, int previousState)
    {
      pin = pin1;
      state = state1;
      location = location1;
      active = active1;
      prevstate = previousState;
    }
};

Button button(7,0,0,0,0);
Button button2(8,0,0,0,0);
Button buttons[2] = {button, button2};

void setup() {
      pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {
   if (digitalRead(button2.pin) == HIGH){
             digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
          } else {
          // turn LED off:
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
          }
       if (digitalRead(button.pin) == HIGH){
             digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
          } else {
          // turn LED off:
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
          }
}
```

this is the code i want to use but it is not working.. the led stays in the on position:

```
void loop(){
  for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(buttons); i++){
    if(digitalRead(buttons[i].pin) == HIGH){
          digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
          } else {
          // turn LED off:
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
          }
    }
}
```

also if i change

```
if(digitalRead(buttons[i].pin) == HIGH)
```

to

```
if(digitalRead(buttons[0].pin) == HIGH)
```

the code works for the first or second button alone in the array.. but not both???

Comment: `sizeof(buttons)` is not the count of elements in the array. it is the size in bytes. so you read some other pins too. use `#define BUTTONS_COUNT 2`

Comment: "If either of the buttons is pressed i want the led to turn on while the button is pressed and stay off if nothing is pressed" - Just put the buttons in parallel and use only 1 I/O pin ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made 4 button objects: button, button2, and buttons[2]. buttons[0] and buttons[1] are full button objects whose first member, .pin, is initialized to the addresses of `button` and `button2`, respectively. This is probably not what you intended.

Did you mean to create:

```
Button buttons[2] = {
   {7,0,0,0,0},
   {8,0,0,0,0}
};
```

, an array of two initialized button objects?

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree that your first sketch is working. I suppose that a very fast blinking led seems to be "on".

When you describe what should happen in a logic way, then you can put that into code.

The logic is: The led is on, if at least one of the buttons is pressed.
In other words: The led is off, if no button is pressed, else the led is on.

This logic has as a result that the led stays on if a second button is pressed and after that the first button is released. I assume this is okay.

For **two buttons** it is possible to check both conditions.

```
if (digitalRead(button.pin) == HIGH || digitalRead(button2.pin) == HIGH)
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
else
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
```

Or test for LOW:

```
if (digitalRead(button.pin) == LOW && digitalRead(button2.pin) == LOW)
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
else
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
```

For **multiple buttons**, a `bool` can be used or the number of pressed buttons can be counted.

A fixed number for the array size is easy and has less chance for a mistake:

```
#define BUTTONS_COUNT 2
```

It is also possible to use `sizeof()`. The total size has to be divided by the size of one element:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(buttons)/sizeof(Button); i++) {
  if (digitalRead(buttons[i].pin) == HIGH) {
    count++;
  }
}

if (count == 0)
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
else
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
```